# Laravel IOC binding - closure vs. automatic resolution

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control, bind, service-provider

I have a question about Laravel's IOC bindings, and especialy - ServiceProviders, who register Facade accessors.

Following official documentation for [IOC](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc)

```
class FooServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('foo', function()
        {
            return new \MyApp\Foo;
        });
    }

}
```

Where later on you can have a Facade, which just returns "foo" as "FacadeAccessor".

Wouldn't it be easier to rewrite this code like that?

```
class FooServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('foo', '\MyApp\Foo');
    }

}
```

It gives pretty much same result, as string will be wrapped into Closure automaticaly and parsed through App::make(). More than that - Foo constructor can have dependency injection if required (while you would have to pass exact objects in first case, and loose automatic resolution, as far as I understood).

Second option looks much cleaner, and unless you will need some additional logic before object initialization - like passing data, initializing other services/objects, etc. - looks better for me.

Maybe there are performance issues related to that? Or I am missing something else?

Interesting fact - in documentation, for Interfaces, Laravel suggests second option instead of Closure, but for ServiceProviders - direct object initialization.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: If you use the second method you can run into infinite loops when 2 classes depend on each other. You create Class A and then it tries to create Class B but then Class B requires Class A so it tries to create it again and so on.

Comment: Also because things often need to be done a little more custom than with dependency injection like this.

Comment: @Robbo - you're right for custom bindings. But for Facades (later on), usualy it's just simple class initialization.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha - my question is: are there any potential/possible problems by using second option. Robbo has answered about infinite loop - which is correct, but that relies on possible application architecture problems.

Comment: Well another reason is the unneeded extra overhead. First way simply initiates a class. Second one utilizes reflection. Also a lot of the time a class might need some configuration variables sent in which reflection can't do.

Comment: @Robbo - OK, gotcha. Probably it's just personal preference. How can I accept your answer? :)

Comment: It isn't really a full on answer which is why I commented and not answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option is the best, closures are largely used to give a nice quick example of the way to do something.

Personally I avoid closures, with the exception of routes, as I like to have the option for the IoC container to run various different dependency injections should it be required.